# Can i get an email when an event is posted on the calendar

Tags: apex, calendar

I created a new calendar for my team, and would like to know about it every time someone creates a new event. An email would be a very good option. Can i do that  using apex?

Answer (score 4):

This was supposedly included in the Summer14 release but product management [later confirmed](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpAuAAK) that it wasn't there.

The workaround I follow is to use a trigger on Event object and use a workflow to send out the email notification. [This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/adding-invitees-automatically-to-a-calendar-event) has details on how you can use a trigger and custom email notifications. You can follow [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm&language=en_US) to understand how to configure the email alerts for Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You can write trigger on Event object (there are a lot of info about writing triggers) or you can  create a workflow rule on Event and add Email Alert as a workflow action.